# How to ignore trailing slashes in Javalin 5?

Tags: java, javalin

There have been a lot of changes to the configuration in Javalin 5. One thing that used to work in previous versions is to "ignore trailing slashes" like this:

```
var javalin = Javalin.create(cfg -> {
    cfg.ignoreTrailingSlashes = true;
}).start(8080);
```

But I cannot seem to find this setting in version 5. So the question is, how do you enable "ignore trailing slashes" in Javalin version 5?

Comment: related, same author: [How to enable "dev logging" in Javalin 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74807996/16320675)

Comment: Yes that was me, I asked these as two different questions because they are two different settings.

Comment: Okay, I can merge them if that is more appropriate?

Comment: I don't think a merge is needed, I just wanted to add a link to related problem

Comment: The [Javalin v4 to v5 migration guide](https://javalin.io/migration-guide-javalin-4-to-5) may help with at least some of these questions. For example, there is a section for "Configuration changes". You may already have seen it - but this link may help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting is now moved to 'routing config' you can now set it as below:

```
Javalin.create(config -> {
    config.routing.ignoreTrailingSlashes = true; 
});
```

See the documentation here - https://javalin.io/documentation#routingconfig